# Creating a new table from existing table in oracle 10g, iSQL*plus

Tags: sql, oracle

I have an 'Employees' table created in my database. I want to create a new table called 'Emp' with the (employee_id, last_name, salary) values or all the values from 'Employee' table.

I have used the following command:

```
select employee_id, last_name, salary into emp from employees;
```

But it is showing the following:

```
into emp *

ERROR at line 2: ORA-00905: missing keyword
```

Can anyone please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [CTAS construct](http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/CTAS).

```
CREATE 
TABLE emp
AS
SELECT employee_id, last_name, salary FROM employees;
```

Comment: Yes it is working.
to select all the data from the existing table

create table emp
as 
select * from employees;

Thank you Mr. Declan_K for the prompt reply